# C# ReadFile _ Method returns string that sliced into jagged array

Tags: c#, readfile, file-read

I need to implement a method according to conditions:

```
char[][] Foo(StreamReader stream, int arraySize) {}
```

Method should return an underlying string that sliced into jagged array of characters according to arraySize.

First condition. If stream is string.Empty and arraySize is 10:

```
return Array.Empty<char[]>();
```

Second condition. If stream is "Lorem" and arraySize is 5:

```
return new char[][]
{
    new char[] { 'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm' },
};
```

Third condition. If stream is "Lorem" and arraySize is 1:

```
return new char[][]
{
    new char[] { 'L' },
    new char[] { 'o' },
    new char[] { 'r' },
    new char[] { 'e' },
    new char[] { 'm' },
};
```

Forth condition. If stream is "Loremipsumdolorsitamet" and arraySize is 5:

```
return new char[][]
{
    new char[] { 'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm' },
    new char[] { 'i', 'p', 's', 'u', 'm' },
    new char[] { 'd', 'o', 'l', 'o', 'r' },
    new char[] { 's', 'i', 't', 'a', 'm' },
    new char[] { 'e', 't' },
};
```

With my solution doesn't works Forth condition; To test my function I've created temp.txt file alongside Program.cs and put there above mentiond values (Lorem, Loremipsumdolorsitamet).

Implementation:

```
char[][] Foo(StreamReader stream, int arraySize) 
{
   long arrLength = 0;

    if (streamReader.BaseStream.Length % arraySize == 0)
    {
        arrLength = streamReader.BaseStream.Length / arraySize;
    }
    else
    {
        arrLength = streamReader.BaseStream.Length / arraySize + 1;
    }

    char[][] array = new char[arrLength][];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new char[arraySize];

        for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = (char)streamReader.Read();
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

call function and test results:

```
int num = 5;

var myArray = Foo(new StreamReader(@"D:\temp.txt"), num);

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
  for (int k = 0; k < myArray[i].Length; k++)
  {
    Console.Write(myArray[i][k] + "\t");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Resalt is:

```
L       o       r       e       m
i       p       s       u       m
d       o       l       o       r
s       i       t       a       m
e       t       ▒       ▒       ▒
```

So, last array length is 5 (but should be - 2) and what the symbol is: '▒' ?

Please help!

Comment: If the stream length is not a multiple of `arraySize`, you are reading beyond the end of the stream. The [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textreader.read) method will return -1 in this case and this is the strange symbol you are seeing.

Comment: So, what should I change in my code? @Klaus Gütter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my error:

```
char[][] Foo(StreamReader stream, int arraySize)
{
    long arrLength;

    if (stream.BaseStream.Length % arraySize == 0)
    {
        arrLength = stream.BaseStream.Length / arraySize;
    }
    else
    {
        arrLength = (stream.BaseStream.Length / arraySize) + 1;
    }

    char[][] array = new char[arrLength][];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        long chunkSize = arraySize;

        if (i == array.Length - 1 && stream.BaseStream.Length % arraySize != 0)
        {
            chunkSize = stream.BaseStream.Length % arraySize;
        }

        array[i] = new char[chunkSize];

        for (int j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = (char)stream.Read();
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .NET6, you can make use of the [Chunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) method to split the input into chunks:

```
char[][] Foo(TextReader stream, int arraySize) 
{
    return stream.ReadToEnd().Chunk(arraySize).ToArray();
}
```

If this is not possible, you may calculate the size of the current chunk as `Math.Min(arraySize, array.Length - i * arraySize)` and use this instead of `arraySize` in your `for (int i...)` loop. (`array.Length - i * arraySize` is the remaining length):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int chunkSize = Math.Min(arraySize, streamReader.BaseStream.Length - i * arraySize);
    array[i] = new char[chunkSize];

    for (int j = 0; j < chunkSize; j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = (char)streamReader.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm on .Net3.1 @Klaus Gütter

Comment: No, it doesn't works. I'm getting error: "Unhandled exception. System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" @Klaus Gütter

Comment: Updated, can you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but for simplicity's sake you can just make a `List<char[]>` and then use `StreamReader.ReadBlock()` to fill a buffer.

Then, based on the number of characters read in that block (conveniently returned as an int by the `.ReadBlock()` method), you instantiate an array of the correct size and add it to the list, using `.ToArray()` at the end to produce your `char[][]`.

```
    char[][] Foo(StreamReader streamReader, int arraySize)
    {
        List<char[]> listOfArrays = new List<char[]>();
        char[] charBuffer = new char[arraySize];
        int charactersInThisBlock;

        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            //fills the charBuffer with as many characters as possible up to its' limit (arraySize)
            //the second parameter (0) simply keeps the function reading from the last unread character
            //the output will tell you the number of characters read into the buffer
            charactersInThisBlock = streamReader.ReadBlock(charBuffer, 0, arraySize);

            //create/fill your new array, and add it to the list
            char[] newArray = new char[charactersInThisBlock];
            for(int i = 0; i < charactersInThisBlock; i++)
            {
                newArray[i] = charBuffer[i];
            }

            listOfArrays.Add(newArray);
        }

        //return char[][]
        return listOfArrays.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I already answered my question. Tanks! @JediOfTheShire

Comment: Great! You might have posted the wrong code, though. If it works for you then you're in good shape, but what you posted gives me the same result that you initially had, with the final array having the three garbage characters caused by calling streamReader.Read() when there is nothing to read.